# Tail log backup message warning before restoring a backup

Tags: sql-server

SSMS 2012

Production server
Production database has Full recovery option.

I want to take a copy of this and restore on to same server with different name.

So I have taken a backup and choose restore but there is a message in the top left corner of the dialog which reads:

> a tail-log backup of the source database will be taken...

Additionally, at this point I would rename the destination database, make sure that  the rename has renamed the mdf and ldf files and that would be good to go.  In this case it hasn't renamed the files so it looks like I will have to do that manually so as not to overwrite the prod database.

I haven't dealt with full recovery databases before.  So questions:

What does the tail-log message mean and what are the implications?
Why did the destination database Rename not rename the mdf and ldf files - that's pretty dangerous huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the tail-log message mean and what are the implications?

Tailog backup message translates to "there is some transaction log generated after your last log backup,so please backup this log so that you can restore to any point in time until this backup"

> Why did the destination database Rename not rename the mdf and ldf files - that's pretty dangerous huh?

backup copies only the files,it won't rename them and i don't see why this is dangerous..

I see you trying to restore to the same instance with different name,so tail log backup is not required,since you tried to overwrite the existing database might be the reason for showing tail log backup message